# I have issue with decoding json ex. '{"a":"b"}'

Tags: php, excerpt, json

Hey I am trying to send JSON data from (WRITE AN EXCERPT (OPTIONAL)) this section. Let say I pass this '{"a":"b"}' as Map now in the wordpress templete I tried to get this so I was able to get but when I decode this any display this so I does not see any thing please help as it took a lot of my time but I was not able to solve.

Here is My Template

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying course results in search pages
 *
 */
global $post;
$post_title         = get_the_title($post->ID);
$image_id           = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$post_img_url       = tuturn_prepare_image_source($image_id, 612, 400);
$post_url           = !empty($post->ID) ? get_the_permalink($post->ID) : '';
// website extra features
$contents           = !empty($post) ? $post->post_content : '';
$extra              = !empty($post) ? get_the_excerpt($post) : '';




$author_id          = get_post_field('post_author', $post->ID);
$author_name        = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);
$post_date          = date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), strtotime(get_the_date())) ;
if ('course' !== get_post_type()) {
    return; // Skip displaying if the post type is not 'course'
}
?>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="tu-articleitem tu-artical-list">
        <?php if(!empty($post_img_url)){ ?>
            <figure>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($post_img_url); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($post_title); ?>">
            </figure>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="tu-articleinfo">
            <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'category', '<ul class="tu-taglinks tu-taglinksm"><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>'); ?>
            <?php if (!empty($post_title)) { ?>
            <div class="tu-arrticltitle">
                <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url($post_url) ?>"><?php echo esc_html($post_title) ?></a></h4>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (!empty($contents)) { ?>
            <div class="tu-description">
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words($contents, 10, '...'); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        // this is the section where i decode json
        <?php if (!empty($extra)){
            echo $extra; // i get results from post EXCERPT
            $data = json_decode($extra); // when i decode i don't see
            echo $data; // any thing in the output
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things is happening here:

### Invalid JSON

If the value of `$extra` isn't a properly-constructed JSON string, then `json_decode( $extra )` is returning `null`. `echo null;` won't print anything to the screen.

### Valid JSON

If `$extra` is a valid JSON string, When you [`json_decode()`](https://php.net/json_decode) it, you'll get an object (specifically, a [`stdClass`](https://www.php.net/stdClass) object). There's no way to `echo` a `stdClass` object; when I try that, I get a PHP warning:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

So your `echo( $data );` line is throwing a warning, which your server is most likely suppressing.

I'd recommend using `var_dump( $data );` to see what's actually happening.

Comment: yes after doing like this var_dump( $data ); i got output which was null. as i was storing json like this '{"a":"b"}' so after storing json like this {"a":"b"} i got the perfect output and now i am able to get data from this Map Thanks

Comment: If this solved the problem for you, please feel free to mark the answer "Accepted". That way others who might have the same problem you're having will see that it's a solution.